# Failed package upload: permission set references Payment that has M-D relationship with Account

Tags: managed-package

I am trying to upload a managed package, it is failing validation and complaining that my permission set references the blng__Payment__c object that has a M-D relationship with Account.

```
<Permission Set Name> references Payment that has M-D relationship with Account.
```

Searching online it is said that M-D relationship are not supported for managed packages, which is fine.

The problem is I don't have control over blng__Payment__c, that's not part of my package, I only reference it in some component I uses.  So I am not sure how I can fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The relevant documentation from the ISVforce Guide is [About Permission Sets and Profile Settings](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.packagingGuide.meta/packagingGuide/packaging_perm_sets_profile_setttings.htm):

> Do they [Permission Sets] include standard object permissions?
> No. Also, *you can’t include object permissions for a custom object in a master-detail relationship where the master is a standard object*

Emphasis mine. You can ship master-detail objects, but you cannot permission them in a packaged permission set. The fact that this object is owned by a different managed package doesn't change how these manageability rules are enforced.

You'll have to remove these object permissions from your Permission Set.

Comment: On the bright side, that error used to throw a GACK, so getting a helpful error is something at least

Comment: Yup it worked, thanks a lot